# How to iterate through input iterator

Tags: c++, io

I need to write a function which takes an input iterator and an output iterator and reads the input stream until completed (my first thoughts are input stream iterator will be a file to be read - so will finish when file contents completely read) and then function will return.

characters read from a text file will simply be output to stdout in this simple experiment.

My problem is I don't know how to:

A) how to iterate through input

B) check when iterator has reached the end of the input.

C) when an error has occurred.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>


bool readTo(std::istream_iterator<char> iit, std::ostream_iterator<char> oit)
{
   bool ret(false);

   // how to check when end of input file? 

   // how to iterate through input

   // how to check if an error?

   char ch = *iit;
   *oit++ = 'c';
   *oit++ = '=';
   *oit++ = ch;
   *oit++ = '\n';

   return ret;
}

int main() {

   std::ifstream strm("test.txt");
   if(strm.good()) {
       bool ret = readTo(strm, std::cout);
       //I only want function to return when readTo read till end of input file 
   }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: (1) Input iterators _always_ come in pairs.  (2) `ifstream` does not magically convert to `istream_iterator`. (3) sounds like your assignment is to rewrite `std::copy`?

Comment: http://ideone.com/m8ZpkF

Comment: You say you don't know how to iterate through input.  Which sounds like you don't know how to iterate.  But your code clearly iterates the _output_, so you do know how to iterate?

Comment: I worked it out in the end.  If my understanding is hazy or mistaken please correct me.

Comment: oh wait, I just realized, `ifstream` _does_ magically convert to an `istream_iterator` O.o  But only in certain cases, which I had never run into before this.  Interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked it out.  It is a little abstract so took me a while.

The std library iterators work on iterators as ranges.  For flexibility, you can pass in eg the whole container as in: vec.begin(), vec.end() or some subset.  But what to do in case of an input iterator?  What is the end.  Well you create an iterator which is not initialised.

ie

```
std::ifstream strm("test.txt");
std::ifstream theend;
if(strm.good()) {
   bool ret = readTo(strm, theend, std::cout);
}
```

Then in readTo() you do this:

```
void readTo(std::istream_iterator<char> iit, std::istream_iterator<char> the_end, 
        std::ostream_iterator<char> oit)

   while(iit != the_end) {
     char ch = *iit;
     *oit++ = 'c';
     *oit++ = '=';
     *oit++ = ch;
     *oit++ = '\n';
     iit++;
   }
```

Or alternatively:

```
void readTo(std::istream_iterator<char> iit, 
        std::string& replaced)
{
    while(iit != std::istream_iterator<char>()) {
        char ch = *iit++;
        if(ch != '$')
           replaced.push_back(ch);
        else
           break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could be `*oit++ = *it++` instead of using `ch`.